# How to webclient.DownloadString() from Youtube autocomplete?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, encoding

I want to get YouTube search autocomplete in Windows Forms Application and this works for English, it doesn't work for Hebrew, what encoding should I choose?

```
string s = webClient.DownloadString(
   @"http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=" + 
   System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(textBoxMain.Text));
```

Here's an example of what I see when I download for a Hebrew word:

> ["\u05DB",["\u05DB\u05E4\u05D5\u05DC\u05D4 \u05E4\u05E8\u05E7 8","\u05DB\u05E4\u05D5\u05DC\u05D4","\u05DB\u05D9\u05E4\u05EA \u05D1\u05E8\u05D6\u05DC","\u05DB\u05D3 \u05E7\u05D8\u05DF","\u05DB\u05DE\u05D4 \u05D0\u05D4\u05D1\u05E0\u05D5","\u05DB\u05D0\u05DF","\u05DB\u05E8\u05DE\u05DC\u05D4","\u05DB\u05E4\u05D5\u05DC\u05D4 \u05E4\u05E8\u05E7 1","\u05DB\u05D5\u05D5\u05E8\u05EA","\u05DB\u05E9\u05D0\u05D7\u05E8"]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As that result looks like an JSON format I applied the JSON deserializer to get its object structure and then process the result to get a list of words. It happens to handle the conversion of those strings rather well.

I used the [JsonConvert class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) to do the heavy lifting.

This is the code to do that trick:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();

string s = webClient.DownloadString(
    @"http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q="
    + "ירושלים");

// s.Dump("raw"); // LinqPad dump

var words = new List<string>();  // collect all words

// make JObject's out of the string 
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s); // using Newtonsoft.Json;

// we got an Array, let's process that
foreach(var item in (JArray)json)
{
   // single value
   if (item is JValue)
   {
       words.Add((string)item);  // add it
   }
   else if (item is JArray) // another array
   {
      foreach(var seconditem in item)
      {
          words.Add((string)seconditem);  // add it
      }
   }
}
```

You can databind the `words` list to one of your controls.

Here is the result in LinqPad for me:

[image]

Get the Newtonsoft.Json classes from NuGet [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).

Comment: How to download JsonConvert class?

Comment: Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'var' because 'var' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'JArray' because 'JArray' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json was in references of VIsual Studio by the way.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2017 updated to latest version a couple of days ago..

Comment: Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'JValue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have: using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: I added: using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; and no errors, testing.